# qtip doesnt display tip point in ie6 and ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, qtip

```
$("#testing").qtip({
   content: 'Presets, presets and more presets. Let\'s spice it up a little with our own style!',
   style: {
      width: 200,
      padding: 5,
      background: '#A2D959',
      color: 'black',
      textAlign: 'center',
      border: {
         width: 7,
         radius: 5,
         color: '#A2D959'
      },
      tip: 'topLeft',
      name: 'dark' // Inherit the rest of the attributes from the preset dark style
   }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<font id="testing">Test</font>
```

Above codes works fine in all browser except ie6 and ie7

**IE6 & IE7:** Tool tip point is not displayed [i had mentioned as `tip:'topLeft'` but tip not appears in ie6 and ie7]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: May I ask why you use $("#testing") to address the tag in dom? Isn't $("testing") correct?

Comment: @YvesR this is basic jQuery! http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not work for me very good too on IE6 & IE7, http://www.jsfiddle.net/G4gU6/.

Actually for me it is just the css which seems to be misunderstood by the IE6 & IE7. You could try to fix it by applying your own css or rewrite the qTip2 css.

For more professional help on that refere to [qTip2 Forum](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/forum-qtip2). Craig will help you ;)

[a bit of search on google ;)](http://www.google.de/search?q=qTip2+error%3A+undifinded&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=de&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3Aofficial&q=qTip+2+IE6&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=6d10e87877d9bf20)

Comment: still ie6 wont displays tip point. I used your sample codes it doesnt played in ie6. tip didnt appeared

Comment: qTip2 definitely works on both IE6&7. what version of jQuery are u using?

Comment: while using qtip2 in my framework. ie6 hangs while using qtip2. qtip2 consumes lot of cache memory. I had changed to use jquery plugin tipsy for tooltip. Thanks.